# change how vim or vi interprets file

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vi

So I am using vim (vi) to edit on command line. Whenever I code in a file that ends in .php, .pl, .cgi, .pm, etc, it matches it up with what language it is and does the proper syntax highlighting. However, I am writing some perl scripts and I am requiring some separate files with the extension ".lib". Is there a way that I could have vim interpret this as a .pl file? right now it just highlights everything in red and looks pretty bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:set filetype=pl`, if you want this to happen all the time, add

```
au BufNewfile,BufRead *.lib set filetype=pl
```

to your .vimrc

Comment: Thanks! Is .vimrc supposed to be in my home directory? because I do not see it in there.

Comment: If you don't have a vimrc, I suggest reading the first part of the user guide :help usr_01.txt.  It will tell you were to find a sample vimrc on your system with some good basic settings in it.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for the `autocmd` command, which will execute some commands based on filenames (or other criteria?)

Try adding something like this to your `~/.vimrc` file:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.lib set syntax=perl
```